# How can i update the view's position who is below the view which i am animating?

Tags: android

I am animating a view firstView and secondView is below it.On firstView i have used object animator's property 'y' to move along in y direction but when i animate i want the secondView also move along with it because view it is below the firstView.How can i do that?

I have tried view.requestLayout() and view.invalidate() but it does not help.

Here is my layout -:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <View
         android:id="@+id/firstView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="top"
         />
         <View    
         android:id="@+id/secondView"
         android:layout_below="@+id/firstView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Animations are only visually moving the view. Logically, the view is still where it was when the animation started, so the secondView will never move up because firsView technically never moved.

There are two ways to handle this depending on how you want the views to act after the animation is complete. If there are no clickable views (buttons, images, etc) within the animated view, you can apply your translation animation to firstView, and a scale animation to the second view. This will give you the effect you are looking for.

However, if there are clickable views inside, the clickable areas will not be affected by the animation and give some weird user experience with detached click areas. To handle this, you will want to create your own animation loop (on a different thread), and update the margin of firstView on each iteration. This will cause the physical location of both views to change along with their contents. If this is what you need, I can go into more detail of how to achieve this with a smooth animation.

**Approach #2 in more detail**

To use the second approach, you will need to create your own animation thread off of the main thread. We do not want to block the main UI thread for the duration of the animation. I'm going to assume you are wanting to move the entire view off of the screen in this example.

```
final View firstView = findViewById(R.id.firstView);

new Thread() {

    public void run() {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int duration = 500; // Make this whatever you want, in ms
        int finalY = -firstView.getHeight();
        double progress = 0;

        while (progress < 1) {

            progress = Math.min((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / (double)duration, 1);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)firstView.getLayoutParams();
            params.topMargin = (int)(progress * (double)finalY);
            firstView.setLayoutParams(params);

            firstView.postInvalidate();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}.start();
```

Comment: yes i have tried that but i want second view height to match_parent.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding your question. What does "move along with the first view" mean?

Comment: when firstview moves in y direction then the secondView should automatically increase its height accordingly or adjust its height by how much amount the firstview moves..sounds good?

Comment: I think I understand what you are looking for now. Please see my edit.

Comment: Which approach do you think fits what you need to do?

Comment: 2nd one...but right now i am using object animator to move firstview and if i decrease the height of firstview then using secondView.requestLayout i am able to see that effect...can you do something about this.

Comment: I have added an example of how you can achieve what you are looking for. You may need to make a couple tweaks to get it exactly as you want, but it gives the general idea of how to create an animation thread.

Comment: i tried out it is changing its top margin(which is working really fine )...is there any way to update layout after moving its x,y position (which is correct way of doing this)??

Comment: i mean you are changing the top margin of view which is workaround of i want right now...this is wht right now i end up with...if i move firstview using object animator and i decrease its height then i am achieving the effect but it jerk somewhere...even though i am finding another way to do it....thnks....vote up..but its a workround so just vote up...:(

Comment: You can use this same approach to change the height. I don't understand why this is a work around if this works...

Comment: okay...let me explain you a bit more...i want to do like stickyheaderlistview like in that when i scroll then header sticks to the top the same effect i want to achieve but i don't want to use stickyheaderlistview.my view hierarchy is like headerview,2 tabs and lastly viewpger.here i want my 2 tabs to stick like header and listview height gets increased and scrolling happen on OnScroll of listview.Are you getting my point?